# limit - show that in infinity, function with constants grow faster that other function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, logarithms, infinity

given two function:

1. $a\:\le\:b\cdot log\left(a\right)\:$
2. $a\:\le\:b\cdot \:log\left(b\right)\:$

i want to show that $b\cdot \:log\left(a\right)\:\le \:b\cdot log\left(b\right)\:$

I made a graph of these 2 functions, you can clearly see that this is true, at infinity, this equation (2) is always above this equation (1)

[image]

I was thinking of showing the limit at infinity:
$\lim _{a\to \infty }\left(\left(b\cdot \:log\left(b\right)\:\right)/\left(\:b\cdot \:log\left(a\right)\:\right)\right) = 0$

I'm not sure if this is a correct way to do it, am I right?

Comment: This is not always true.  For example take $a=e^4$, $b=e^3$.  Then $a\le b\log(a)$ and $a\le b\log(b)$, but $b\log(b)\not\le b\log(a)$.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 do not imply what you are trying to show